# How to extract value from a dict in a string - Pandas / Python

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame with one feature, df['Computed Data'].

| Computed Data |
| --- |
| '{"stats":{"TypeCount":{"1 |
| 25":"31","8":"31"}},"plaintsCard":[{"root":"old","plaintsCount":1,"residencyCount":1}],"Count":62,"Status":{"activable":"10","activated":"18","inactivable":"3"},"Counta":0,"invoiCount":"31"}' |
| '{"Count":33,"invoiCount":"11","stats":{"TypeCount":{"1":"9","4":"22","11":"2"}},"plaintsCard":[],"Count":0,"Status":{"activated":"0","activable":"9","inactivable":"1"}}' |
| '{"Count":79,"invoiCount":"32","stats":{"TypeCount":{"1":"29","4":"32","18":"3","23":"15"}},"plaintsCard":[],"Count":0,"Status":{"activated":"0","activable":"28","inactivable":"2"}}' |
| '{"Count":80,"invoiCount":"32","stats":{"TypeCount":{"1":"31","4":"42","13":"1","23":"6"}},"plaintsCard":[],"Count":0,"Status":{"activated":"0","activable":"27","inactivable":"6"}}' |
| '{"stats": {"TypeCount": {"17": "27"}}, "plaintsCard": [], "parcelsCount": 27, "Status": {"activable": "9", "activated": "2", "inactivable": "16"}, "Count": 0, "invoiCount": "0"}' |

I want to extract the "membersStatus", "activable" part from every string and to put it in a new column.

I have tried to use ast.literal_eval() and it is working but only when I apply it to one value

```
x = ast.literal_eval(df["Computed Data"][0])
x["membersStatus"]["activable"]
```

```
'10'
```

It gives me : '10'. Which is what I want but for every dict in "Computed Data" and to put it in a new column.

I tried to do it with a for loop :

```
for n, i in enumerate(df["Computed Data"]):
    x = ast.literal_eval(df["Computed Data"][n])
```

```
ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x13699c610>
```

I don't know how can I change what I did to make it work.

Can you Help please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use:

```
import json
df['Computed Data']=df['Computed Data'].apply(json.loads)
df['activable']=df['Computed Data'].apply(lambda x: x['membersStatus']['activable'])
```

if there are nan values:

```
df['Computed Data']=df['Computed Data'].apply(lambda x: json.loads(x) if pd.notna(x) else np.nan)
df['activable']=df['Computed Data'].apply(lambda x: x['membersStatus']['activable'] if pd.notna(x) else np.nan)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but when I tried ypur answer I get the following error : 
"the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not float"

Comment: probably you have nan values.

Comment: i edited my answer. Can you check it ?

Comment: Yes It's working, thanks a lot Clegane. I am not very familiar with the lambda function but I am going to check, thank's again.

Answer (score 0):

you can use apply methods to extract them:

```
df['member Status']=df['Computed Data'].apply(lambda x:eval(x)['membersStatus']['activable'])
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. But When I try this I got the following error :
"name 'null' is not defined"

Comment: if you have null values , you should transform it to none